# expand/contract tableview rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Anyone out there willing to explain to me how/why when I expand the row (tableviewrow) with the welcomeLabel that contains the text that the rows will expand one by one and stay open, but when I click on the closeLabel contained in the closeLabel.addEventListener, all the open rows close not just the one referenced in the event listener.  Many thanks.

```
 openLabel.addEventListener('click',function(e){    
        wrow.height = 100;
        var labelrowID = e.rowData.rowID;
        var labeltext = e.rowData.labelText;
        welcomeLabel.height = 100;
        texttableView.updateRow(e.index,wrow);
        texttableView.data[0].rows[labelrowID].children[0].text = test;
    });

 closeLabel.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(wrow.height === 100){
        wrow.height = 32;
        var labelrowID = e.rowData.rowID;
        labeltext = e.rowData.labelText;
        welcomeLabel.height = 32;
        texttableView.updateRow(e.index,wrow);
        texttableView.data[0].rows[labelrowID].children[0].text = labeltext;
        //texttableView.setData(welcomeRows);
    }
    });
```

Comment: oops, I see I didn't change texttableView.data[0].rows[labelrowID].children[0].text = test; to texttableView.data[0].rows[labelrowID].children[0].text = labeltext....but that doesn't make any difference in the result.;

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more context? An `app.js` that I could actually run to reproduce? At first sight I don't see anything wrong with your code but much depends on the context.